# How can throughput be greater than the bandwidth? Is this a valid reason?

Tags: networking, security, compression, throughput

I asked this question on networking engineers but it was closed as off topic since it wasn't for professional application. Hope it fits better here.

I'm studdying for the CISSP secuirty exam and a true and false question asked

> Data Throughput of a telecommunication link has to be lower than the
>   Bandwidth of the same communication link.

The given answer was false because compression could be used. Is this valid reasoning? Throughput seems like a very nebulous term to me, does it have a clear definition? At what point is the payload of a packet considered the actual data, for example if somethings a 1 MB ZIP file would you say the throughput is 2 MB since the ZIP file is 1 MB when extracted, or what if the "compression" is built into the system like with [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)?

I'm adding the security tag to this, since CISSP is a security certification.